# How to use Youtube Api in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api, zend-framework2

So i start using Zend Framework 2 and Youtube Api, so i installed the Gdata from my composer :

```
"zendframework/zendgdata": "2.0.*"
```

but when i tried to call it in my contoller i got this error :

```
Class 'Zend_Loader_Autoloader' not found
```

**so this is my Action :**

```
public function mediaAction()
{
    \Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

so please if someone has any idea or solution i will be very appreciative :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the explanation at https://github.com/zendframework/ZendGData, this component is unmaintained, so you may want to use the official Google one instead.

For your specific issue, there is no `Zend_Loader_Autoloader` class in ZF2, so remove that line. You don't need to setup an autoloader since you installed the component via. composer. The classes were refactored to use PHP namespaces, so `new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();` should probably be something like `new \ZendGData\YouTube();`.